# Highlight cells containing text from a list of strings in Excel

Tags: string, excel, formatting, conditional-statements, highlight

I want to search for any string from a list within a list of cells and highlight them.
Example: 
[image]

In this case cells `A1`, `A3` and `A6` should be highlighted. It's like to press ctrl+f, insert "car" and highlight result cells, repeated for every keyword. How I can automate this?

Comment: So your entries in column b are the keywords you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting.

Select A1:A6 and then in conditional formatting (on Home tab) use the "use a formula to determine which cells to format" option with this formula

`=COUNT(SEARCH(B$1:B$3,A1))`

format as required > OK

Comment: What does the COUNT function do in this?

Comment: COUNT is defined here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/count-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c

Essentially "SEARCH" returns a vector (in this case with 3 elements), and COUNT counts how many of those 3 elements are numbers, returning the result.