# Highlight cells which is not contained in any of the strings in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I want to search for any string from a list within a list of cells and highlight the cell which is not found in any of the strings. Example:

name of the 1st sheet: first

> **name**
>
> microsoft
>
> usa
>
> perl
>
> java
>
> html
>
> sql

name of the 2nd sheet: second

> **website**
>
> www.perl.com
>
> www.usa.com
>
> sql.com
>
> www.com.java

In this case cells microsoft and html should be highlighted from the first sheet as those cells are not contained in any of the second sheet.

I use conditional formatting. I select from A2 to A7 in the first sheet then in conditional formatting (on Home tab) use the "use a formula to determine which cells to format" option with this formula. I used this code below and turn blue.

=NOT(COUNT(SEARCH(first!B$1:B$3,second!$A1)))
It does not work.

I referred to this stackoverflow for help. The website is [Highlight cells containing text from a list of strings in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184192/highlight-cells-containing-text-from-a-list-of-strings-in-excel)

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEARCH() uses a single cell as its target. You need a function that evaluates a range of cells.

You can use Countif with wildcards to identify the cells that don't have a match, like this:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,"*"&Sheet1!A2&"*")
```

If you want to use that concept in a conditional formatting formula, try a rule with a formula along the lines of

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,"*"&$A2&"*")=0
```

[image]