# Extracting data from a large database by ID code

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a project at the moment where I'm trying to extract actor data for 10,000 movies from a IMDB.com database file (a .tsv - tab-separated value file) with about 45 million rows.

I have an unique key for each IMDB movie - I just need to look each one up in the database and extract five columns from rows that match the key. (The final output should have several rows (several actors) per movies).

I've tried conditional highlighting after splitting the database into more manageable pieces
(following the formula suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21185850/16254929)
But this seems very time-consuming and doesn't allow for all the data to be processed while away from the keyboard. Also, it is liable to freezing or crashing.

This is a sample screenshot from Excel (columns A to F are from the .tsv file, column M is the list of 10,000 movies by their key - which I'm trying to pair with column A):
[image: screenshot]

Any good alternatives?

Thanks for your time.

edit:
the first ten rows of the .tsv file are as follows

```
tconst  ordering    nconst  category    job characters
tt0000001   1   nm1588970   self    \N  ["Self"]
tt0000001   2   nm0005690   director    \N  \N
tt0000001   3   nm0374658   cinematographer director of photography \N
tt0000002   1   nm0721526   director    \N  \N
tt0000002   2   nm1335271   composer    \N  \N
tt0000003   1   nm0721526   director    \N  \N
tt0000003   2   nm1770680   producer    producer    \N
tt0000003   3   nm1335271   composer    \N  \N
tt0000003   4   nm5442200   editor  \N  \N
```

Comment: Do you want an answer in Excel or will a command line solution work?

Comment: Also can you paste the first 5-10 rows of the TSV?

Comment: This would be much easier in a data base.   Do you have Access?  45million rows... it might just fit.

Comment: Use SAS or similar - excel is fine for proof of concept but so **slow** after.

Comment: I've added the first ten rows of the .tsv file to my initial post. I have Access but I haven't used it for ages. A command line solution might be beyond me unless it is simple (I have limited skill with programming). Will look into SAS, thanks.